# Python - vpython won't run files

Tags: python, undefined, vpython

I'm having trouble running functions in Vpython.

I'm very new to this, I have a basic understanding of python, but I am experienced in other programming languages.

When I use Python's IDLE, I can save a function in a file named "test.py", hit F5, and run them in the command window. When I open VIDLE, I try to do the exact same thing, and it gives me the

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1
    f(2)
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

error.

I'm running Python2, and I need to use vpython because the rendering window in the regular IDLE is very laggy and needs to have `rate()` called a bunch of times.

Any ideas? I've tried saving the file in the default directory that VIDLE lets me save, and also in the directory that IDLE is able to work from (i.e., if I put a function in said directory, IDLE can run it, but VIDLE can't).

EDIT:

The one I'm trying to run is the following:

```
from visual import *

def f(x):
    b = box(vector = (0, 0, 0), color=(1, 0, 0))
    b.rotate(angle = pi/4, axis=(1,0,0))
    b.pos
    b.pos +=vector(1,0,0)
```

Comment: What's the content of your script?

Comment: @solarc I just added the content of the script to the question.

Comment: I see no problem with you script, where are you calling `f(2)`?

Comment: @solarc I call f(2) in the Vpython shell. It works in the regular python shell, but gives me a NameError in the vpython one.